# How do I get the server name in Format-Table?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

This is probably a version issue, but I simply need to get the server name into the `Format-Table` PowerShell command.

```
$compArray = Get-Content C:\Users\Me\Documents\ServerList_All.txt 
$Proc = foreach ($strComputer in $compArray) {
    Get-WMIObject Win32_Service | Where-Object {
        $_.Name -like 'SQL*' -or
        $_.Name -like 'MSSQL*' -or
        $_.Name -like 'OLAP*' -or
        $_.Name -like 'MSDTS*' -or
        $_.Name -like 'MSOLAP*' -or
        $_.Name -like 'ReportServer*'
    } | Sort-Object -Property Name | Format-Table $strComputer, Name, State
}
$Proc | Out-File C:\Users\ME\Documents\ServerStatus_All.txt
```

This works in PS v2:

```
| Sort-Object -Property Name | Format-Table Name, State
```

This does not, but does work in PS v3:

```
| Sort-Object -Property Name | Format-Table $strComputer, Name, State
```

Error:

> Format-Table : Cannot convert System.Management.Automation.PSObject to one of the following types {System.String, System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock}.

The only difference is the `$strComputer` variable.  I am reading from a text file, and everything is beautiful in v3+.

No, I cannot upgrade to a newer PS version on the server I am running this from, sadly.

Comment: What is the value of `$strComputer`? Maybe show us the code with which you populate it

Comment: Its a servername, read from a list (.txt file)...if that is in there V2 fails, take it out and everything else works perfectly.   It all works in V3.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, full code added...pretty generic stuff

Comment: @PetSerAl Perfect...that did exactly what I needed :)   can you place as the answer?

Comment: WMI objects are quite unlikely to have a property whose name matches the computer's name, so I'm not sure what your desired output is. If you want to include the hostname with the service names you would normally use the `PSComputerName` (or `__SERVER`) property.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you in both...

```
$compArray = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).Name
$Proc = foreach ($strComputer in $compArray) {
    Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_Service -ComputerName $strComputer | 
    Where-Object {
        $_.Name -like 'SQL*' -or
        $_.Name -like 'MSSQL*' -or
        $_.Name -like 'OLAP*' -or
        $_.Name -like 'MSDTS*' -or
        $_.Name -like 'MSOLAP*' -or
        $_.Name -like 'ReportServer*'
    } | 
    Select-Object -Property  @{Name = 'Computer';Expression={$strComputer}}, Name, State | 
    Sort-Object -Property Name | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize
}
$Proc


# Results

Computer  Name            State  
--------  ----            -----  
LABSQL01 MSSQLFDLauncher Running
LABSQL01 MSSQLSERVER     Running
LABSQL01 SQLBrowser      Stopped
LABSQL01 SQLSERVERAGENT  Running
LABSQL01 SQLTELEMETRY    Running
LABSQL01 SQLWriter       Running



Computer  Name                 State  
--------  ----                 -----  
LABWSM01 MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID Stopped
```